# regex &align:%HORIZONTAL%|%VERTICAL%

Tags: php, regex

I would like to have a regex that matches something like this:

```
&align:%HORIZONTAL%|%VERTICAL%
```

%HORIZONTAL% may be "left" or "right" or "center"

%VERTICAL% may be "top" or "bottom" or "center"

I tried something like this:

```
&align:(left|right|center)\|(top|bottom|center)
```

And I got this:

```
Array(
[0] => &align:left|center
[1] => left
[2] => top
)
```

What would I have to change to get only one match at all? 
The [1] and [2] must not be possible.

Comment: don't capture your subpatterns: `(?:left|right|center)`

Comment: @cbuckley: You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Also, I find it hard to believe that `[0]` would contain `center` and `[2]` would contain `[top]`...

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses serve two purposes — grouping and capturing. To get the grouping you want without capturing the matches, use `?:`:

```
&align:(?:left|right|center)\|(?:top|bottom|center)
```

Manual reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php